# Sending access token over http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, https, devise

I have a rails 4.x web app which also exposes an API for use by native clients. I use devise and devise_token_auth for user authentication. From my native client I get an access token from the server by sending user name and password over https. But on subsequent calls to server from the native client I don't want to use https because if the content from the server has http links in it, I get "Mixed content" errors like this:

`"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.com/mypage' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://someserver.com/someresource'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."`

Is it safe to send the access token over http?

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to send xxx over http? **No**

- The data can be intercepted
- The data can be modified

Is it safe to send the access token over http? **No**. It mean that the authentication is almost useless, anybody that can see the request can impersonate your users.